# What are the best modulators for vocoders?

Tags: plug-ins, vocoder, virtual-instruments

I'm experimenting with vocoders and I was wondering what are the best modulators for a vocoder ?

Does it have to have a lot of harmonics ? I don't know...I'm a newbie here.
I use VSTi like Absynth and Massive but there are a lot of presets, wich one is better ? Wich kind of sound should I use ?

Wow i think my english is pretty bad here isn't it ? :D

Answer (score 3):

There is no best.  It is our differences that make us unique.

Comment: I totally agree!

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on what the desired outcome is... 
What sort of sound are you trying to make?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally the human voice, but the possibilities for sound design are endless

It doesnt have to have a lot of harmonics, i have got my best results by having a carrier signal that is rich in harmonics.